# KeyBindings.swing not updating value at first keypress

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm a bit of a noob at using swing and keybindings, but I wanted to try to make a simple platformer where the player (an oval in this case) could be moved with the WASD-keys. I've seen that KeyBindings is preferred for this.

The problem now is that I can't seem to get the object moving in the right direction at the first keypress.

Here is my code, including the keybindings and the actions:

```
class Player extends JPanel {
    private int x = 100;
    private int y = 100;
    private int velX = 0;
    private int velY = 0;

    private boolean left, right, up, down = true;


    public Player() {
        new Timer(10, taskPerformer).start();

        keyBindings();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        setBackground(Color.black);
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 5);
    }

    ActionListener taskPerformer = evt -> {
        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;
        repaint();
    };

    //KEYBINDINGS
    public void keyBindings() {
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "startMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "stopMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "startMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "stopMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "startMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "stopMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "startMoving");
        this.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released S"), "stopMoving");

        this.getActionMap().put("startMoving", Move);
        this.getActionMap().put("stopMoving", stopMove);
    }


    //ACTIONS
    Action Move = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("a")) {
                if (left) {
                    left = false;
                    velX--;
                }
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("d")) {
                if (right) {
                    velX++;
                    right = false;
                }
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("w")) {
                if (up) {
                    velY--;
                    up = false;
                }
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("s")) {
                if (down) {
                    down = false;
                    velY++;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Action stopMove = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("a")) {
                    System.out.println(left);
                    left = true;
                    velX++;
                } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("d")) {
                    right = true;
                    velX--;
                } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("w")) {
                    up = true;
                    velY++;
                } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("s")) {
                    down = true;
                    velY--;
                }
        }
    };

}
```

The "game" starts with an oval on the screen, but when I press a button (e.g. A), the oval doesn't move at all. Then when I release the button, the oval starts moving the other way. When I press the opposing button (so after the A, the second button press would be D) and release it, the oval stops and I can move it properly in both directions. Then the same happens for W and S, since they're using velY instead of velX is my guess.

Now I would like to know if anyone knows how to fix this, with that I mean, moving in the right direction on first keypress.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @camickr Actually, only `down` is true initially.  This confusion is why Java recommends against defining multiple variables or fields on one line…

Comment: @VGR `This confusion is why Java recommends against defining multiple variables or fields on one line` - yes I never define multiple variables on a single line. Must admit I thought that would be a shortcut for assigning true to all the values. Thanks for the correction. (deleted my comment to avoid confusion).

Comment: ActionListeners with if/else logic is generally not a good design.A better approach is to define a generic `Action` and then pass in parameters to that `Action` to define the movement. Then you create a unique Action fir each KeyStroke you want to handle. Check out the `MotionWithKeyBindings` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for an example of this approach. The `KeyboadAnimtion` is a full example that allows animation when hold multiple keys at one time.

Comment: @VGR thanks for responding! I thought that that would work. I now replaced this with proper initialization of the variables and it works like a charm :)

Comment: @camickr while I've thought about passing the parameters to the function, but in that instance, I would not know how to make sure that the function is only called once when pressing the button, instead of having it run all the time, since holding down a button gives the same response over and over, which would make "velX++" just speed up the player very quickly.

Comment: I gave you a link to working examples. You can play with that code to try and understand how it works, or, you can debug your own code. We can't tell you what is wrong because we can't run/debug your code. You need to add System.out.println(...) statements to see what happens when the Action is invoked and what the value of your variables are when the component is painted. Once you understand how both approaches work, you can then decide which approach you want to use.

Comment: I would say the main difference between the two approaches is that you "increment" the velocity with each KeyStroke, but my approach "sets" the velocity with each KeyStroke so there is no need to worry about the velocity increasing.